# Show that if $x^p-x-1$ is reducible in $F[x]$ where $F$ has characteristic $p$ then it splits in $F[x]$ into monic distinct factors.

Tags: abstract-algebra

So far, I have shown that the function is separable, after all, $D_f(x)=-1$ so they are relatively prime. I am having trouble showing that it splits. Our field $F$ contains $GF(F_p)$ thus it contains the splitting field of $x^n-1$. However, i am not sure how helpful that is.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $x$ is a root means that $x^p = x+1$; but $(x+1)^p = x^p+1$, so $x+1$ is a root too.

Comment: thats cool! this shows that if we have 1 root, we have all of them. However, how do, we show we have one root?

Comment: Suppose $fg = x^p - x -1$ in $F$, and look at a field extension where there's a root (hence all of them) $\alpha$, and look at the degree $\deg (f)-1$ term of $f$ : it's of the form $\sum_{i\in I} (\alpha + i)$ for some $I\subset \mathbb F_p$, so $|I| \alpha + k$ for some $k\in \mathbb F_p$. Therefore $|I|\alpha \in F$. Therefore, if $x^p-x-1$ is reducible, there is such a decomposition with $0 < |I| < p$, which implies $\alpha \in F$. I think there should also be a Galois-type argument to prove that